# Allow arrow keys in Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, razor, onkeyup

I am performing alphanumeric validation and now I am doing that user can only enter an alphanumeric value and also allow alphanumeric values only while pasting. So I used the following regular expression

```
function OnlyAlphaNumeric(evt) {
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
if ((charCode > 32 && charCode < 48) || (charCode > 57 && charCode < 65) ||    
                    (charCode > 90 && charCode < 97) || charCode > 122) {
    return false;
}
else {
    return true;
   }
}
```

And for preventing the copy and paste,

```
function CPOnlyAlphaNumeric(evt) {

     $(evt).val($(evt).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, ' '))

}
```

These two functions are calling from the following onkeypress and onkeyup methods such that is given below as shown that

```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProductName, new { @class = "form-  
       control", @onkeypress = "return OnlyAlphaNumeric(this);", @onkeyup=   
        "return CPOnlyAlphaNumeric(this);" })
```

This works for alphanumeric validation, but it doesn't allow the cursor to move left side for editing the text. So what will change I should do in my Regular Expression.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem has nothing related to regular expressions.

When you press any key (including left/right arrow) you take value of input, replace all forbidden characters and **set the value of the input**. When last action is done it's the browser native behavior to move the cursor to the end of input.

You can check what is the pressed key and if it's left/right arrow to skip the manipulation of input value.

```
function CPOnlyAlphaNumeric(evt) { 
    var code = evt.which ? evt.which : event.keyCode;

    // 37 = left arrow, 39 = right arrow.
    if(code !== 37 && code !== 39)
        $(evt).val($(evt).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, ' '))
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r6zxajt7/)

However this is not a good solution because it will result in a terrible behavior (you won't be able to use shift for mark, the cursor will be moved at the end after first typed letter in the middle of word etc..)

A better solution could be to 'clean' the input value let's say 500 ms after user stop typing.

```
var timeout = null;

function CPOnlyAlphaNumeric(evt) {
    if(timeout)
        clearTimeout(timeout);

    timeout = setTimeout(function(){ 
        $(evt).val($(evt).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, ' '))
    }, 500);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r6zxajt7/1/)

Please note that you need to add the validation on server side as well (and maybe before the form submit, because user can hit enter to submit the form before the 'cleaning' of input is triggered).

Comment: Can I write this code without 'setTimeout' function?. Is there any possible?

Comment: If I copy and paste any text, then 'replace' also taken 500 ms. So I don't want to use the 'setTimeout' function. Please help me if you know another solution @ Viktor Bahtev

Comment: The first solution doesn't use 'setTimeout` but as I said it results in a terrible behavior. I would recommend to use the solution with 'setTimeout'. If you don't want 'setTimeout' only for pasting a text you can use two functions - one with setTimeout for `keyup`, `keydown` or `input` event and another without setTimeout for handling the `paste` event.

Comment: I tried it in a lot of ways, but I cannot find a solution for it,So please help me. Can you give a sample code?

Comment: I tried, but after typing, the cursor moves to end @ Viktor Bahtev

Comment: if you change the value of input with javascript it will `always` result in moving the cursor to the end. It's the browser native behavior and you can't change this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71004/discussion-between-md-aslam-and-viktor-bahtev).

Comment: I got a solution, such that is given below as shown that 
function CPOnlySomeSpecialChar(txtName) {
    //    //$(evt).val($(evt).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, ''))
    //$(evt).val($(evt).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9@.()&+-]/g, ' '))
    if (txtName.value != '' && txtName.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9 @&)(.+-]*$/) == null) {
        txtName.value = txtName.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 @&)(.+-]/g, '');
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, it may solve your problem.

```
  var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");

  var charCode =(typeof event.which == "number") ?event.which:event.keyCode

  var key = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

  if (!(charCode == 8 || charCode == 0)) {

      if (!regex.test(key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem with keyDown event is that you cant suppress the display of keys in the textfield (only alpha numeric in my case). You can do it in only keyPress event. But you cant get navigation keys in keyPress event, you can only track them in KeyDown event. And some of the keys $,%, have the same e.which that arrow keys has in keypress event. which is causing issues for me to write the logic to allow arrow keys but restrict the text to only Alpha numeric. Here is the code I came up with. Working fine now.

```
    onKeyPress: function(e){
            var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\b ]+$");
            var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
            var allowedSpecialKeys = 'ArrowLeftArrowRightArrowUpArrowDownDelete';
            var key = e.key;

            /*IE doesn't fire events for arrow keys, Firefox does*/
            if(allowedSpecialKeys.indexOf(key)>-1){
                return true;
            }

            if (regex.test(str)) {
                return true;
            }

            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.cancelBubble = true;
            return false;
    }
```